# li menu links going underneath content when page loads + css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-lists

http://jsfiddle.net/msbyuva/QPQqs/

[image: li Menu Links]
Hi I have a menu formed using

```
<ul class="topnav">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Configuration", "Configuration", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reporting", "Reporting", "Home")
                            <ul class="subnav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Pipeline", "Pipeline", "Pipeline", null, new { target = "_blank", Url = "http://storespipeline/stores/" })</li>
                            <li>D2C OBI Reports</li>                  


                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Device Utilization", "DeviceUtilization", "DeviceUtilization")</li>

                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Display Audit", "DisplayAudit", "DisplayAudit")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("TrueVUE Reports", "TrueVUE", "TrueVUE")</li>                                 
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
```

CSS:

ul.topnav
        {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            background: #f6f6f6;
            font-size: 1em;
            color: Black;
        }
        ul.topnav li
        {
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 15px 0 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        ul.topnav li a
        {
            padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
            color: black;
            display: table;
            text-decoration: none;
            float: left;
        }
        ul.topnav li a:hover
        {
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

```
    ul.topnav li span.subhover
    {
    }
    ul.topnav li ul.subnav
    {
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 25px;
        background: #f6f6f6;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        height: auto;
        display: none;
        float: left;
        min-width: 100px;
        width: auto;
    }
    ul.topnav li ul.subnav li
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 4px 10px 0px 10px;
        height: auto;
        line-height: 100%;
    }

    html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a
    {
        float: left;
        width: 150%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a:hover
    {

    }
</style>
```

When I click on a link example -- Display Audit -- when the page gets loaded -- the menu link is underneath the page content... that can be seen in the image (the last two links go underneath the page content)..... how can I display the menu link above the page content??

I am using IE7, CSS 2.1

Comment: Where is the CSS part? could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I updated the question part with css and html code.... here is the link for fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/msbyuva/QPQqs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a z-index. For z-index to work both the navigation container and the content container need to have a position of relative, absolute or fixed. For your example I would suggest a relative positioning.

```
.topnav {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1000;
}

.yourContentContainer{
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: You may need to use seeral different positions, like relative or fixed for the menu, and absolute for the content/reports, as I have noticed that two relatively positioned divs occasionaly interact. For example, your dropdown menu may actually force the report to shift to a position further down the page, which looks ugly and is really annoying. Be sure to check multiple browsers too, some may compute the relationship between the divs inconsistently.